# Application crashes in mfc71u.dll

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

My application uses VC++ 2003. While executing in the Unicode release mode it crashes at

*CMDIFrameWnd* pFrame = new CMainFrame;*

in InitInstance() of startup project. The error message shows that the application crashes at mfc71u.dll

Click the link to see the  [error message](https://picasaweb.google.com/110359478928607192645/MSDNForum?authkey=Gv1sRgCKS71_mKyor5lAE#5576867825512020114)

The same application runs well on other systems.

Please suggest me what could be the reason for the crash.

Thanks

Shyam

Comment: _The same application runs well on other systems_. On which systems does it run OK and on which does it not?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted more information such as:

- A stack trace to the fault.
- The source code around the crash.
- The exception generated.

This is the bare minimum information you should automatically include with any crash.